# Does still make sense to use SHA1?

Tags: hash, sha, iot

I'm working with Arduino and [hash-based signatures](http://www.pqsignatures.org/) which are signature schemes that use only hash functions. Due to the constraints of an Arduino I was thinking about using SHA1 as the underlying function of my hash-based signature. But I'm not sure if it still makes sense to use SHA1 due to its vulnerabilities. Is there a scenario in which would be acceptable to use SHA1?

Comment: I think this should be better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com. If you look at [Hash-based Signatures:
An Outline for a New Standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/post-quantum-2015/papers/session5-hulsing-paper.pdf) you will find at page 3 that *"while MSS requires a collision resistant
hash function, XMSS reduces this requirement to
weaker security assumptions...at MD5 and SHA1, there exist
‘practical’ collision attacks while the weaker properties
XMSS uses (like second-preimage resistance) are still
unbroken and there is not much progress in this
direction so far"*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the tips! I'll check this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would always be "in comparison to what else?"

In this moment, SHA-1 is weaker than SHA-2:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms

It's got known weaknesses, a smaller number of security bits, increased risk of collisions, and SHA-2 is fairly prolific, has a good performance, and is fairly widely accepted.  So... why not use something better?

**There is a reason** - compatibility.  There will always be some suitably old technology out there that simply cannot (or has not) been upgraded to use the current recommended best practice.  So the big question is - does your business model benefit more from interoperability, or cryptographic strength?

My not-spending-lots-of-time-doing-math-research answer on SHA-1 vs. SHA-2 would be that it's a no brainer - SHA-2 is better.  But if you told me that your biggest customer has a substantial investment in SHA-1 only technology and can't improve the system... well... I'd probably advise finding a way to limit the scope of where and who you do SHA-1 with, and then make sure you have that customer sign a nice sounding waiver that they understand that you can't be entirely responsible for the risks of using a not-best-practices algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The risk of using any algorithm is down to your risk appetite. Only you know if the risk of a SHA1 attack is something you are willing to accept.

I would use it if that was the only option for none mission critical or sensitive data. But that's only a personal opinion.